# Phrase for expressing victory and teasing the opponent

Tags: phrase-requests, slang

I'm looking for a slang term that can be used when someone has defeated their opponent and the opponent is speechless and gave up the challenge. So he might want to to brag about how weak the opponent was. To be more clear, something like:

> Haha! Don't have anything to say eh?

**Update**:
Seems like there was a misunderstanding about what I'd like to know. I've seen a scene in which a scientist was answering every question he'd been asked. Suddenly a guy asked a silly question which doesn't have a clear answer and when the scientist remained silent, the guy started jumping up and down and bragging about defeating him. The video was not in English and I was curious what that guy could say if he were speaking English.

Comment: *"slang"* is not a noun here, it's an adjective. So you can't ask for "a slang" - you need "a slang word/term/expression/etc."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unfortunately since you deleted your answer I couldn't fully read your comment. Could you please re-add your comment here?

Comment: Sorry - didn't realise you wouldn't be able to read it. All I said was if you're asking for a suggestions as to what the heckler might say in this context, I think the question itself is Not Constructive. There are a huge number of things he could say, none of which is inherently "the correct answer" here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see. I couldn't find the suitable phrase to search and find the synonyms. So I asked it here. Didn't realize it could be considered Not Constructive. Do you suggest any place that I can find synonyms or appropriate English expressions for specific situations?

Comment: It really depends what if any meaning the heckler actually intends to convey, which you haven't specified very clearly. Is he trying to press home his advantage? Taunt the speaker? Boast about how clever he's been? To repeat: there's no special expression for exactly your context. As fakefake commented previously, *"How do you like them apples?"* is a particularly "idiomatic" taunt, but who's to say if that would suit your heckler?

Comment: Well, guess now I see what you meant by saying it's "not constructive". However, I think the heckler was trying to Boast about how clever he's been. Although have not mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Younger people might say, "In your face!" in that kind of situation. It has an entry in [Urban Dictionary.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=in%20your%20face)

Comment: @Kamyar: I think tne problem is it's Too Localised if you want your heckler to say something simultaneously triumphalist ***and*** making reference to the fact that the speaker is unable to respond. People have offered a variety of triumphalist expressions that would fit many other contexts. Personally, I still like the old lady's [Up yours, nigger!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM4-r4pN1PY) in Blazing Saddles, which you still hear now and then in the UK. But I think that's probably no longer acceptable to most Americans.

Comment: If it's scientists you're talking about, you could use the word "Bazinga!" – but that's more from recent pop culture (TV's _The Big Bang Theory_) than from classic English. (See the short definition [HERE](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-does-sheldon-mean-by-bazinga-on-the-big-bang-theory) and the longer explanation [HERE](http://www.sheldonfan.com/origin-sheldon-coopers-bazinga.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase “Who's your daddy?” is used in the manner asked about.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_your_daddy%3F_%28phrase%29) says:

> It is commonly used as a boastful claim of dominance over the intended listener. ... An early use of the phrase occurs in the 1979 film *Scum* ... Widespread provocative use of the phrase began as early as the late 1980s ... The expression was further popularized in a well known 1991 comedy routine by Dennis Miller.

Answer (score 3):

The term *gotcha* is used as an interjection or a noun to reflect stumping an adversary or forcing someone into no-win position.  [American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/gotcha) defines it as an interjection

> used to indicate understanding or to signal the fact of having caught or defeated another.

[Websters' New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gotcha) says

> that one has caught, captured, or gained power over someone or something

As a noun, [Merriam-Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gotcha) defines it as

> an unexpected usually disconcerting challenge, revelation, or catch; also: an attempt to embarrass, expose, or disgrace someone (as a politician) with a gotcha